# How to convert curl code into java

Tags: java, android, xml, curl

I am new in android and java I want to get access data from this API.

All we need to do convert this into java code

```
curl --include --header "X-Access-Token: YOUR_API_TOKEN_HERE" "http://api.travelpayouts.com/v2/prices/latest?currency=rub&period_type=year&page=1&limit=30&show_to_affiliates=true&sorting=price&trip_class=0"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your given API has a header and basic GET format. This can be converted in Java  easily.

See the code example,

```
public String httpGet(String s, String api_token) {
    String url = s;
    StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder();
    httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); // create new httpClient
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url); // create new httpGet object
    httpGet.setHeader("X-Access-Token", api_token);

    try {
        response = httpclient.execute(httpGet); // execute httpGet
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            // System.out.println(statusLine);
            body.append(statusLine + "\n");
            HttpEntity e = response.getEntity();
            String entity = EntityUtils.toString(e);
            body.append(entity);
        } else {
            body.append(statusLine + "\n");
            // System.out.println(statusLine);
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        httpGet.releaseConnection(); // stop connection
    }
    return body.toString(); // return the String
}
```

Now call the function and pass the url along with your header API token,

```
httpGet("http://api.travelpayouts.com/v2/prices/latest?currency=rub&period_type=year&page=1&limit=30&show_to_affiliates=true&sorting=price&trip_class=0", YOUR_API_TOKEN)
```

Comment: Hey response function not found in android

Comment: Where we define this response

Comment: Hey man please where we define response variable  and which type

Comment: try this, HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);

Comment: One more thing  httpGet.releaseConnection(); // stop connection I delete this line this function can't work in android studio

Comment: Its a good practice to stop the connection after the task has been done, however its solely up-to you. Rest of the things should work properly without the line.

Comment: Sir please answer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31891317/how-to-use-this-travel-api-in-my-ajava-code